# Accessing globals of subclass' module

Tags: python

I've recently decided to write a helper class to output some information from a module. It looks like this:

```
class VarPrinter(object):
    @classmethod
    def save(cls):
        globals = cls.globals
        #do stuff with globals...
            for i in things_to_output:
            ...

# subclass in another module
# e.g. in foo.py
class FooPrinter(VarPrinter):
    things_to_output = ('foo', 'bar')
    globals = globals()
```

The question is: is there a way to get `globals()` array of a module where `VarPrinter` is subclassed so that I don't need to pass it explicitly like `globals = globals()`. In other words, the solution I want behaves as if I repeated the code of baseclass in a module of subclass. Initially I thought `eval` would help to do this but this was not the case.

Comment: Are you saying you want `VarPrinter` to access the globals of the module where `FooPrinter` is defined, or vice versa?  Why are the classes storing references to their global environment in the first place?  That seems like a fragile design.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take `cls.__module__` and look it up in `sys.modules`.